# Fetching an NSManagedObject with Unique Identifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Do NSManagedObjects come with any kind of unique identifier?

I need to fetch a couple of objects but there is a large chance they have identical attributes, so how can I, after fetching these objects, differentiate them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Every [NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/) has an [`-objectId`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BAJGEDIA) accessor which returns an [`NSManagedObjectID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/) instance. These uniquely identify the object in question. You can then retrieve the object again using either of NSManagedObjectContext's methods [`-objectWithID:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJIFIGA) or [`-existingObjectWithID:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW2).

Note that if the object has not yet been saved after insertion, the object ID will be a temporary ID that will change when it's saved. You can force a persistent ID to be assigned with [`-[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW7), although this is just as expensive as an actual save.